# Does LdapTemplate close connections each time?

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-ldap, active-directory-group

I have an application that is using Spring LDAP 1.3.1.  It is creating the [LdapTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) in a Spring context at startup, passing it in to my application.  The LDAP string I am connecting to is in reality a VIP appliance with multiple Active Directory servers behind it.

The application is used to create a group hierarchy, and does so in several steps.  First, it creates any new groups, then removes any deleted groups, then updates and changed groups, and finally it updates the parent of any new or moved groups.

In that last step, in order to do the move, I have to look up the group, then look up it's parent, and finally update the Member list of the parent to remove the child.

Here is where the problem starts.  Every so often, but not every time, I have a run in which the group is added but when the code tries to set the parent, it fails because the new group isn't there yet.  I believe what is happening is that Spring LDAP is reconnecting on each call, and because I am going through a VIP and the AD server is round-robin'ed, I think the newly added group hasn't replicated, so selecting the group returns null and my parent update fails.  Basically I think I am running into a race condition with AD replication.

So, long explanation short: Does Spring LDAP 1.3.1, and in particular the `LdapTemplate`, create a new connection each time, or am I misunderstanding how it works?  Is there a way to make it use a pooled connection, either by configuration of the `LdapTemaplate` or by setting `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool`?  If I used only one connection for the entire application run, it should solve the replication (if that is what's occuring) problem in that I would be stuck to one AD server and not bouncing around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To all future Devs who may stumble across this post, this is how I fixed the issue...

In Spring LDAP 1.3.2, [SingleContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/SingleContextSource.html) does not have a constructor that takes a [ContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/ContextSource.html), but rather only one that takes a [DirContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html?is-external=true).  I didn't see any means to get a single `DirContext` from my [LdapContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSource.html), so I was unable to use the suggestion of [ig0774](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274466/ig0774).

However, having read the Oracle documentation, I found that it has built-in since 1.4.1 a VERY simple [pooling mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html).  Further reading in the Spring API docs for `LdapContextSource` showed that it has the ability to turn this pooling mechanism on through a call to [setPooled(boolean)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.html#setPooled%28boolean%29).  This basically makes it so that the call to `close()` on the connections doesn't not really close the connection, but rather returns it to the "pool".  Since my application is one big linear thread, and only one "connection" is opened at a given time, this has the net effect of causing it to simply use the same connection, thus bypassing the issue I was seeing were my updates were working faster than the replication.  After turning on the built-in pooling, my errors have seemingly stopped.

Note that this is NOT a good means to implement a pooling scheme for LDAP.  As the JavaDoc says, this built-in pooling mechanism has many flaws.  If you need pooling, then you are MUCH better off using Spring LDAP's [PoolingContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/pool/factory/PoolingContextSource.html).  In my case, however, I wanted the opposite of a "pool", so things seemed to work out for me in that regard.

The other option would have been to simply not use the VIP but rather connect directly to a single Active Directory server, but then I loose fail-over ability.

Answer (score 1):

You could be right, as `LdapTemplate` does appear to close the connection after every operation. One way of mitigating your problem would be to switch your Spring configuration so that you are using a [`SingleContextSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/SingleContextSource.html) as a wrapper for your current `contextSource` supplied to your `LdapTemplate`. Depending on your configuration, this may look something like this:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="contextSource"
      class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
      <property name="url" value="ldap://localhost:389" />
      <property name="base" value="dc=fabrikam,dc=com" />
      <property name="userName" value="cn=superuser,dc=fabrikam,dc=com" />
      <property name="password" value="secret" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="contextSourceWrapper"
      class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.SingleContextSource">
      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="ldapTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="contextSourceWrapper" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can I pass that to a `TransactionAwareContextSource`?  From the JavaDoc it looks like I should be able to.

Comment: I have been looking and looking for a way to use `SingleContextSource`.  As of 1.3.1, it seems that the constructor has changed to only allow construction via the `DirContext`, and not via a `ContextSource`.  The above example will not work.